# Cannot retrieve the description of pubsub node with other users with Smack library

Tags: java, android, xmpp, publish-subscribe, smack

i'm trying to retrieve the description of a pubsub node. I can set this field but when i'm going to retrieve the value, only the owner of the node can get it.
I'm using this command line:

```
mgr.getNode(categoria).getNodeConfiguration().getField("pubsub#description").getValues().get(0);
```

where mgr is a PubsubManager, categoria is the name of the pubsub.
Why only the owner can see it?
How can i allow non-subscribed user to see the description of a node before subscribing it?
Access type is open.

Comment: Which XMPP server are you using ? Your question is likely to be dependant on XMPP server implementation.

Comment: I'm testing that the error became when i call the getNodeConfiguration() method.
Here is the log:

W/AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:576)

Comment: Can you debug at the XMPP level and check what the XMPP server replies ?